# Mysql order by where alias

Tags: mysql, sql

What I want to do is to get nearest city of a latitude and longitude.
My cities table has 3 fields: lat,lng,radius:
My query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM cities 
where st_distance_sphere(point(@lat, @lng), point(lat, lng)) <= area LIMIT 1
```

My problem is that I want to order them by distance. (the `st_distance_sphere(point(@lat, @lng), point(lat, lng))`) gives the distance.
But apparently I can't just alias `st_distance_sphere(point(@lat, @lng), point(lat, lng)) as distance` and specify `ORDER BY distance`.

So how would I order result based on distance?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the query to look like this:

```
SELECT c.*,
        st_distance_sphere(point(@lat, @lng), point(lat, lng)) as dist
FROM cities c
HAVING st_distance_sphere(point(@lat, @lng), point(lat, lng)) <= area
ORDER BY dist
LIMIT 1
```

This uses a MySQL extension that allows conditions in the `HAVING` clause even without a `GROUP BY`.  The `HAVING` clause allows you to use column aliases for the conditions without having to use a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
select b.* from (
SELECT a.*, st_distance_sphere(point(@lat, @lng), point(a.lat, a.lng)) as distance FROM cities a) b where b.distance<= area order by b.distance limit 1
```